# Where can I find documentation for the name mangling scheme used by SunPro CC

Tags: c++, sparc, name-mangling

I have a few SPARC binaries that have been compiled with what seems to be the SunPro CC compiler. The symbols in the binary are referring to a very early C++ implementation (pre-namespaces) and look like this:

```
__0oHistreamrsRUl.
__0oHistreamrsRi.
__0oHistreamrsRf.
__0oKistrstreamdtv.
__0oHistreamrsPc.
__0oKistrstreamctPCc.
__0oNIostream_initdtv.
__0oNIostream_initctv.
```

Looking at these, I'm guessing that they correspond to the following methods:

```
istream::operator >>(unsigned long);
istream::operator >>(int);
istream::operator >>(float);
istream::~istream();
istream::operator >>(char *);
istream::operator(const char *);
ostream_init::~ostream_init();
ostream_init::ostream_init();
```

To make further progress, I want to understand the mangling scheme used here, but my Google-fu is too weak. Where can I find documentation on the name mangling scheme used here?

Comment: No namespace support?  That has to be back in the Sun Workshop days.

Comment: The binary is over 15 years old. I can make some guesses as to the mangling scheme (`__0` prefix, `H` = symbol of 7 chars follows, etc) but it would be nice to have a reference. I've searched open source repositories hoping to find a demangler but haven't found one that understands this particular demangling scheme.

Comment: I wonder if someone on Retrocomputing can find the info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following documentation on archive.org, as part of Sun WorkShop™ for Solaris 2.x

[mangling.ps](https://archive.org/download/SunWorkshopVol5No1/Sun%20WorkShop%E2%84%A2%20for%20Solaris%202.x%20Volume%205%20Number%201.iso/SPROmrcpl%2Freloc%2FSUNWspro%2FSC4.2%2FREADMEs%2Fmangling.ps)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `c++filt` directly. Pay attention to not use the one from `binutils`. Make sure to use the right install path, eg:

- `/opt/SolarisStudio/solarisstudio12.3/prod/bin/c++filt`

Comment: while this helps with the specific problem, it does not actually address the question as asked; are there any docs on the mangling scheme used?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky That's an actual pretty good exercise to do then ! If OP has access to compiler, it should be possible to write the documentation (eg. https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling)